# External Dell monitor has ghosting effects on dropdowns and terminals

Tags: linux-mint, display, multi-monitor, monitors

I have an external monitor setup that works perfectly in Windows, but in Linux Mint, I get weird ghosting effects in the monitor.

The monitor is a DELL SP2309Wc with resolution of 2048 x 1152.

No ghosting when the mouse is on the laptop screen.

I am using an HDMI cable.

Answer (score 2):

I can't leave comments yet, but is the screen connected via VGA or DVI? HDMI (Type B).

The problem may be elsewhere, but if you have different display ports and have a different cable, connect the screen just to check.

Try lowering the resolution, do you get any ghosting?

Try the recommendations for your screen Model from Dell:

[image]

Comment: HD 1080p has the same ghosting

Comment: What brand model is screen (Dell ????) there may be some settings like refresh rate to check.

Comment: DELL SP2309Wc is the one

Comment: Iv'e update my answer, can you try the recommendations from Dell (probably won't do anything) but never know.